# In Typescript, How to check if a string is Numeric

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, this shows an error saying isNaN accepts only numeric values

```
isNaN('9BX46B6A')
```

and this returns false because `parseFloat('9BX46B6A')` evaluates to `9`

```
isNaN(parseFloat('9BX46B6A'))
```

I can still run with the error showing up in Visual Studio, but I would like to do it the right way.

Currently, I have written this modified function -

```
static isNaNModified = (inputStr: string) => {
    var numericRepr = parseFloat(inputStr);
    return isNaN(numericRepr) || numericRepr.toString().length != inputStr.length;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript Converting a String to a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667713/typescript-converting-a-string-to-a-number)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a string is a valid number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number)

Comment: This isn't really related to TypeScript, since you only need to add parameter types to the JavaScript solutions. In the case that you mentioned you could write `isNaN('9BX46B6A' as any)` and you wouldn't get the error

Answer (score 570, accepted):

The way to convert a string to a number is with `Number`, not `parseFloat`.

```
Number('1234') // 1234
Number('9BX9') // NaN
```

You can also use the unary plus operator if you like shorthand:

```
+'1234' // 1234
+'9BX9' // NaN
```

Be careful when checking against NaN (the operator `===` and `!==` don't work as expected with `NaN`). Use:

```
 isNaN(+maybeNumber) // returns true if NaN, otherwise false
```

Comment: does that mean that doing this: if (isNaN(+possibleNumberString))  is a valid way of checking?

Comment: Why would you use `Number` above `parseInt` or `parseFloat`? `Number('')` gives 0 while `parseInt('')` gives `NaN` which is more in line to what I expect.

Comment: As mentioned *in the original question*, `parseInt('9BX9')` (and `parseFloat('9BX9')`) will return `9`, not `NaN`. If you don’t want the conversion of an empty string to 0, check explicitly for empty string first.

Comment: pay attention: NaN is a number but NaN === NaN and NaN == NaN always are false, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801601/why-does-typeof-nan-return-number

Comment: If you want to check for it, use `isNaN(Number(what_ever))` instead of `Number(what_ever) === Nan`.

Comment: Can anyone point me to the documentation for `Number('1234')` ? I'm looking through https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/ but I can't find it, and I don't know what kind of function it is so I don't know what to search for - but I'd like to learn more. Thanks!

Comment: @sauntimo `Number` is not a TypeScript thing, it is a [built-in EcmaScript constructor function](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number-constructor) which accepts a value and returns a number primitive when called as a function rather than a constructor.

Comment: @CSnover ah, thank you - just what I needed. Much obliged!

Comment: There is one more side to this. If you use Number('1234') then you can't directly use + (for sum) e.g. `Number('1') + Number('2')` will return compile time error as typescript doesn't allows use of + operator between two Number types. However the unary operator '+' is much better and convenient to use in such use cases i.e. `(+('1')) + (+('1'))` would compile just fine.

Comment: @Invoker Nope. `Number('1') + Number('2')` is a valid expression in TypeScript. If you are experiencing an error, you’re probably calling the Number constructor with `new`, which creates a `Number` object instead of a `number` primitive.

Comment: Actually, it also returns an error if you have two class properties of type Number and try to add their values as even when you didn't explicitly used the `new` keyword to declare the property. Although you are correct that `Number('1') + Number('1')` may not return an error in this case but it doesn't rule out the possibility of other cases where someone tries to add two properties of Number type. Just saying that using unary `+` operator is much more reliable as mentioned in your post. Here is a [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2031) where these cases are discussed.

Comment: @Invoker `Number('1')` will generate the same type and value as `+'1'` no matter what. Your assertion that the unary `+` operator is “much more reliable” in this case is wrong. Your problem is an unrelated bug where you’ve used `Number`, which is the object type, instead of `number`, which is the primitive type. TypeScript doesn’t allow implicit conversion to the primitive type in order to perform an arithmetic operation. It has nothing to do with this question, or this answer.

Comment: Use isNaN(string) does not work anymore, you receive this error
`TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.`

Answer (score 73):

```
function isNumber(value?: string | number): boolean
{
   return ((value != null) &&
           (value !== '') &&
           !isNaN(Number(value.toString())));
}
```

Comment: If `value` is undefined, won't this throw an exception when trying to call `toString()` on it?

Comment: @LCIII - if the value is `undefined` then `value != null` is `false`, so the if statement (in the return) will not pass the first line of code. Because there is an `&&` between the if lines

Answer (score 58):

**Update**

***This method is no longer available in rxjs v6***

---

I'm solved it by using the *isNumeric* operator from *rxjs* library (importing *rxjs/util/isNumeric*

`import { isNumeric } from 'rxjs/util/isNumeric';`

.
.
.

```
var val = "5700";
if (isNumeric(val)){
   alert("it is number !");
}
```

Comment: This method is no longer available in rxjs v6.

Comment: Seems excessive to require React just to detect if a number is numeric...
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/util/isNumeric.ts <-- for the curious

Comment: Richard lee please update your answer.

Answer (score 18):

My simple solution here is:

```
const isNumeric = (val: string) : boolean => {
   return !isNaN(Number(val));
}

// isNumberic("2") => true
// isNumeric("hi") => false;
```

Comment: This will consider space, empty etc as number

Comment: This doesn't work because if any number is included in the string, it will be interpreted as a number.

Comment: Those cases does not work: Number("") ==0 
Number(null)== 0
Number(true)==1 
Number(Infinity)==Infinity
Number([])==0

Comment: This is useful in cases where you just need to check whether "casting" to number will succeed, and considering whitespace as "0", which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [`Number.isFinite()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite) function:

```
Number.isFinite(Infinity);  // false
Number.isFinite(NaN);       // false
Number.isFinite(-Infinity); // false
Number.isFinite('0');       // false
Number.isFinite(null);      // false

Number.isFinite(0);         // true
Number.isFinite(2e64);      // true
```

Note: there's a significant difference between the global function `isFinite()` and the latter `Number.isFinite()`. In the case of the former, string coercion is performed - so `isFinite('0') === true` whilst `Number.isFinite('0') === false`.

Also, note that this is not available in IE!

Comment: But...TS2345: Argument of type '"1"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'. It it needs to be Number.isFinite(Number('0'));

Comment: This answer doesn't seem like it is answering the question. They asked `if a string is Numeric`, but the function you are suggesting that they use `Number.isFinite` will always return `false` for every `string`, even if that `string` is numeric. The answer could be salvaged if you rewrite it to use the global `isFinite` instead

Answer (score 9):

Simple answer:  (watch for blank & null)

```
isNaN(+'111') = false;
isNaN(+'111r') = true;
isNaN(+'r') = true;
isNaN(+'') = false;   
isNaN(null) = false;
```

https://codepen.io/CQCoder/pen/zYGEjxd?editors=1111

Answer (score 8):

I would choose an existing and already tested solution. For example this from rxjs in typescript:

```js
function isNumeric(val: any): val is number | string {
  // parseFloat NaNs numeric-cast false positives (null|true|false|"")
  // ...but misinterprets leading-number strings, particularly hex literals ("0x...")
  // subtraction forces infinities to NaN
  // adding 1 corrects loss of precision from parseFloat (#15100)
  return !isArray(val) && (val - parseFloat(val) + 1) >= 0;
}
```

[rxjs/isNumeric.ts](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/util/isNumeric.ts)

Without rxjs isArray() function and with simplefied typings:

```js
function isNumeric(val: any): boolean {
  return !(val instanceof Array) && (val - parseFloat(val) + 1) >= 0;
}
```

You should always test such functions with your use cases. If you have special value types, this function may not be your solution.
[You can test the function here.](https://repl.it/repls/YellowgreenSpatialLevel)

Results are:

```
enum         : CardTypes.Debit   : true
decimal      : 10                : true
hexaDecimal  : 0xf10b            : true
binary       : 0b110100          : true
octal        : 0o410             : true
stringNumber : '10'              : true

string       : 'Hello'           : false
undefined    : undefined         : false
null         : null              : false
function     : () => {}          : false
array        : [80, 85, 75]      : false
turple       : ['Kunal', 2018]   : false
object       : {}                : false
```

As you can see, you have to be careful, if you use this function with enums.

Comment: Typescript calls this a "type guard"

Answer (score 5):

Considering that your variable could be string or number or any type - for full numbers (non-floats) in Angular/Typescript you can use:

```
var isFullNumber: boolean = 
    Number.isInteger(Number(yourVariable)) && yourVariable !== null;
```

Edited as pointed out by @tarrbal - we CANNOT use just:

```
Number.isInteger(yourVariable);
```

To prove check out these 3 tests:

```
let testVariables = [0, 1, "0", "1", "A", {}, -3, 0.1, NaN, null, undefined]; 

let isFullNumber: boolean;
let ix: number = 1;
testVariables.forEach(v => {
isFullNumber = Number.isInteger(v);                         // <---
console.log(ix++, ': ', v, isFullNumber);
})

console.log('--------------');

ix = 1;
testVariables.forEach(v => {
isFullNumber = Number.isInteger(Number(v));                 // <---
console.log(ix++, ': ', v, isFullNumber);
})

console.log('--------------');
ix = 1;
testVariables.forEach(v => {
isFullNumber = Number.isInteger(Number(v)) && v !== null;   // <---
console.log(ix++, ': ', v, isFullNumber);
})
```

and these 3 results:

```
1   :       0           true
2   :       1           true
3   :       0           false <- would expect true
4   :       1           false <- would expect true
5   :       A           false
6   :       {}          false
7   :       -3          true
8   :       0.1         false
9   :       NaN         false
10  :       null        false
11  :       undefined   false
----------------------------
1   :       0           true
2   :       1           true
3   :       0           true
4   :       1           true
5   :       A           false
6   :       {}          false
7   :       -3          true
8   :       0.1         false
9   :       NaN         false
10  :       null        true <- would expect false
11  :       undefined   false
----------------------------
1   :       0           true
2   :       1           true
3   :       0           true
4   :       1           true
5   :       A           false
6   :       {}          false
7   :       -3          true
8   :       0.1         false
9   :       NaN         false
10  :       null        false
11  :       undefined   false
```

Comment: `Number.isInteger` just tells you if `yourVariable`, which is already a `number` type, is an integer. Does not work with strings. So, `Number.isInteger(Number(yourVariable))` might do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

here's my trusty isNumber function. use it wisely

```
function isNumber(numStr: string) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(numStr)) && !isNaN(+numStr)
}
```

tests

```
it("test valid isNumber", () => {
  expect(isNumber("0")).toEqual(true)
  expect(isNumber("-1")).toEqual(true)
})

it("test invalid isNumber", () => {
  expect(isNumber('" 1000 "')).toEqual(false)
  expect(isNumber('" 100,00.00 "')).toEqual(false)
  expect(isNumber("100,00.00")).toEqual(false)
  expect(isNumber("")).toEqual(false)
  expect(isNumber(null as any as string)).toEqual(false)
  expect(isNumber("abc")).toEqual(false)
  expect(isNumber("10%")).toEqual(false)
  expect(isNumber("#10")).toEqual(false)
  expect(isNumber("2^10")).toEqual(false)
  expect(isNumber("2!")).toEqual(false)
  expect(isNumber("(10)")).toEqual(false)
  expect(isNumber("10px")).toEqual(false)
})
```

Comment: isNumber('4')  return // true; this is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time the value that we want to check is string or number, so here is function that i use:

```
const isNumber = (n: string | number): boolean => 
    !isNaN(parseFloat(String(n))) && isFinite(Number(n));
```

---

[Codesandbox tests](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-shamir-kq6f6).

```
const willBeTrue = [0.1, '1', '-1', 1, -1, 0, -0, '0', "-0", 2e2, 1e23, 1.1, -0.1, '0.1', '2e2', '1e23', '-0.1', ' 898', '080']

const willBeFalse = ['9BX46B6A', "+''", '', '-0,1', [], '123a', 'a', 'NaN', 1e10000, undefined, null, NaN, Infinity, () => {}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Scrolled through each answer and was surprised that this simple one-liner wasn't presented yet:

```
const isNumber = (val: string | number) => !!(val || val === 0) && !isNaN(Number(val.toString()));
```

Comment: Doesn't work with `"3e44"`

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
 function isNumeric(val: unknown): val is string | number {
  return (
    !isNaN(Number(Number.parseFloat(String(val)))) &&
    isFinite(Number(val))
  );
}
```

```
// true
isNumeric("-10");
isNumeric("0");
isNumeric("0xff");
isNumeric("0xFF");
isNumeric("8e5");
isNumeric("3.1415");
isNumeric("+10");
isNumeric("144");
isNumeric("5");

// false
isNumeric("-0x42");
isNumeric("7.2acdgs");
isNumeric("");
isNumeric({});
isNumeric(NaN);
isNumeric(null);
isNumeric(true);
isNumeric(Infinity);
isNumeric(undefined);
isNumeric([]);
isNumeric("some string");
```

Comment: Doesn't work with `"3e44"`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to match a numeric string like this:

```js
const RE = /^(?:[+-]?(?=\.\d|\d)(?:\d+)?(?:\.?\d*)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)$/

function isNumericString(str) {
  return RE.test(str)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const isNumeric = (value: string): boolean =>
  !new RegExp(/[^\d]/g).test(value.trim());
```

If you want to allow decimal point

```
   const isNumeric = (value: string): boolean =>
      !new RegExp(/[^\d.]/g).test(value.trim());
```

Comment: Warning, this will not work negative numbers.  `console.log(  isNumeric("-123")); // false`

Answer (score 0):

This works for special cases, e.g. nulls

```
if(!isNaN(yourValue) && yourValue !== true && yourValue !== false) {
    // then it's a number
} else {
    // then it's not a number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's typed version for utils, or sth

```
export const isNumber = (value: unknown): value is number =>
  Number.isFinite(value);
```

Comment: Read the question again. The title may be confusing, because it mentions `TypeScript`, but the question is actually about regular `JavaScript`. They ask about checking values of a `string`, not about checking the `type` of a variable. Your function `Number.isFinite` will return `false` for every `string`. And your return type `value is number` is not relevant here, because we want to check if the `string` is `numeric` or not. And even in your own use case it wont work since it will return `false` when the `value` is `Infinity` and the type of `Infinity` is `number`.

Answer (score -3):

if
var sum=0;
var x;

then, what about this?
sum+=(x|0);

Comment: How does that answer OP's question `How to check if a string is Numeric`? Please explain.

Answer (score -6):

Whether a string can be parsed as a number is a runtime concern. Typescript does not support this use case as it is focused on compile time (not runtime) safety.

Comment: It's enough of a concern to mark it as an error, as if to suggest it's not correct.