# Typescript: Parsing a String with characters to a number

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
var number1 = Number("1123 mm");
```

I want to parse this String to a number, 1123 to be exactly. However, I get NaN if I do this. Does anyone have a suggestion how I could parse this to a number?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667713/typescript-converting-a-string-to-a-number#14668510

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript Converting a String to a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667713/typescript-converting-a-string-to-a-number)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), you can use `parseInt` and `parseFloat`.

```
var number1 = parseInt("1123 mm", 10); // 1123
var number2 = parseFloat("115.65 lkjsdf"); // 115.65
```

Answer (score 1):

Number only works for valid number strings and booleans.

You want to use parseInt()

```
var number1 = parseInt("1123 mm");
```