# ERROR TypeError: co.Number is not a function

Tags: angular

I am trying to multiply two strings with Angular.

```
<h5>{{Number(someString) * Number(someOtherString)}}</h5>
```

but I am getting this error:

> ERROR TypeError: co.Number is not a function

How can I multiply two strings with Angular in the HTML?

**Edit:**

*gsc* pointed out that I can simply multiply the strings together.

```
{{'4'*'3'}}
```

> 12

However, be careful

```
{{'4'+'3'}}
```

> 43

Comment: Do you really need the `Number` calls? Have you tried using `someString * someOtherString`?

Comment: Wow. That works. I did not expect that.

Comment: the syntax here is not very intuitive, please also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42122654/3779853

Answer (score 8):

Inside a component template, you don’t have access to global JavaScript objects (like `Number`, `window`). You can only use properties and functions from your component class (and Angular stuff, like pipes). Finally, you don’t need to invoke `Number` constructor to convert your `string` to `number`, because JavaScript will do it for you.