# How to converto to int string value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I tried to do that like as:

```
const int = Number(this.getCurrentYear());
```

It return me string current year

Comment: no, `int` will be definitely be a number

Comment: try parseInt(this.getCurrentYear());

Comment: What is the definition of `getCurrentYear`?

Comment: @EmirMaljanovic: That won't make any difference to the *type* of `int`. `Number` definitely returns a number.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14667713/5115768

Comment: Stack Overflow is a *very* active place. When you post a question (or answer), *stick around* for a few minutes to address comments, such as JaromandaX's point that no, that doesn't give you a string.

Comment: `const int = +this.getCurrentYear();` placing a `+` sign before the string will convert to int

Comment: @Aravind: That does exactly what the OP's code does, just implicitly rather than explicitly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes agreed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must parse it to an int

```
var numberAsString = "4566";
var numberAsInt = parseInt(numberAsString);
```

so change your code to this

```
const int = parseInt(this.getCurrentYear());
```

if this doesnt work either this.getCurrentYear() must not be a number(its either undefined or contains alphabets or symbols)

Comment: This is actually worse then OP has with using `Number()`