# Angular2 / Typescript : Wrong Result in Easy multiplication

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two variables of type number:

```
row.priceList
row.markUp
```

And a simple multiplication:

```
row.priceList = row.pricePurchase * row.markUp;
```

Why if I set **pricePurchase** to 1500 and **markUp** ad 2.3, the **result** is 3449.9999999999995 ?!

This is just a simple formula, with plain values...

Thanks to support

Comment: Try by using number(row.pricePurchase) * number(row.markUp);

Comment: No way, I number() is not typescript function

Comment: It works in typescript too.

Comment: I don'w know but I can't compile Abel

Comment: take look [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36134133/6651984)

Comment: @AbelValdez If you open a console 1500*2.3 = 3449.999999..995, A solution might be  `Math.round(1500*2.3)` this is a limitation of double arithmetic in all double implementatons, not just JS, as is stated in the duplicate

Comment: Turns out that 2.3 is not a "plain value" when represented in binary. The situation is similar to representing 2/7 in decimal.