# Numbers comparison in typescript

Tags: typescript, comparison

My question might be silly, and I actually have a workaround to solve this issue. But I'm still interested in why it happens.
I have two numbers in my typescript file. Here is their definition.

```
mAlarmValue:number;
levelValue:number;
```

In my HTML input box which I also set the attribute type="number", I filled a number for mAlarmValue. After that, I did a comparison between those two numbers. Here is what I did.

```
console.log('Value =',this.mAlarmValue);
console.log("levelValue=",this.levelValue);
if (this.mAlarmValue <= this.levelValue) {
  console.log("true");
}
```

And this is the actual console output.

```
Value = 10
levelValue= 5
true
```

Apprently 10 is greater than 5, but the result showed otherwise. My workaround is to convert the number to string and then convert it back to number.

```
console.log('Value =',this.mAlarmValue);
console.log("levelValue=",this.levelValue);
if (parseFloat(this.mAlarmValue.toString()) <= this.levelValue) {
  console.log("true");
} else {
  console.log(false)
}
```

Now it shows the correct result.

```
Value = 10
levelValue= 5
false
```

Does anyone have idea what's going on here? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of the `value` property of an `HTMLInputElement` is always string, even if you set `type="number"`. I'm guessing that somewhere in your code you have something like this:

```
this.mAlarmValue = $('#Alarm').val() as number;
```

Although this will compile, since the values are really strings, you will get the wrong result at runtime (for example, "10" < "5" is true). To fix this, you need to use `parseFloat` at the moment you read from the `<input>` element, such as

```
this.mAlarmValue = parseFloat($('#Alarm').val() as string);
```

Or, in case you're using Vue.js, make sure that you use `v-model.number="mAlarmValue"` to correctly convert string values to numbers.

Comment: Very clear explanation. Thanks a lot. I assigned the value in HTML, not typescript. <input type="number" class="form-control" step="any" (input)="mAlarmValue = $event.target.value">

Comment: OK, so you're using Angular. Then it will be `mAlarmValue = parseFloat($event.target.value)`.

Answer (score 4):

> My workaround is to convert the number to string and then convert it back to number.

You can do something like below in latest **`es6`**

- converting string to number =>   **`this.mAlarmValue = +this.mAlarmValue`**
- converting number to string =>  **`this.mAlarmValue = " " + this.mAlarmValue`**

Then  you can do something like below for your case

```
    if (+mAlarmValue >= +levelValue) {
         console.log(true);
    } else {
         console.log(false);
    }
```

for more information about converting the types in Typescript check here

**[TypeScript Converting a String to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667713/typescript-converting-a-string-to-a-number)**

Comment: This is a very clever and concise way to do type conversion. I'll probably use it in my personal projects only as it seems to lose a bit readability to me.

Comment: Yeah, but I never mind using latest ECMAScript features..   :)