# why three numerical values are not adding in javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to add 3 prices like 18+10+5 but it is returning answer as 18105 instead of 33.as shown in code totalPrice, extraFoodPrice, extraNonFoodPrice are number type.

```
finalAmount() {
return this.totalPrice + this.extraFoodPrice + this.extraNonFoodPrice;
}
```

Comment: may be those variables type is string. if those are string use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667713/typescript-converting-a-string-to-a-number

Comment: `return parseInt(this.totalPrice) + parseInt(this.extraFoodPrice) + parseInt(this.extraNonFoodPrice)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least `totalPrice` and/or `extraFoodPrice` is a string and not a number. You probably get this value from an `<input>` field in your code. You should parse it to number first:

```
finalAmount() {
  return (+this.totalPrice || 0) + (+this.extraFoodPrice || 0) + (+this.extraNonFoodPrice || 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably variables are strings.
Try adding an extra + before each variable to convert to number, or use parseInt.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, they are strings. Check the code which could affect those, possibly change it into strings and fix those problems. Sharing the code here could be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are adding strings.

Try to explicitely convert the values to numbers with parseFloat for example.

Exact syntax and details here : https://gomakethings.com/converting-strings-to-numbers-with-vanilla-javascript/

hth

Comment: Nota : for prices, you certainly should use floats and not integers