# Calculate two field value sum in angularjs template file

Tags: angularjs

I want to calculate two field sum
my code like

```html
                            {{(((greyDemandPrice/orderQuanity)*orderedProduct.ExchangeRateBDT)+orderedProduct.EffectiveWeavingCharge)}}
```

result showing like
101.4232635 24.32
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Because javascript are treating them as string not integer, use parseInt().

```
{{(((greyDemandPrice/orderQuanity)*orderedProduct.ExchangeRateBDT)+parseFloat(orderedProduct.EffectiveWeavingCharge))}}
```

Comment: When i using parseInt() or parseFloat() result become white. Nothing showing

Comment: try to output one by one with parseFloat() and see which one is not giving output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667713/how-to-convert-a-string-to-number-in-typescript

Comment: also convert to numbers before sending to template, https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-convert-a-string-to-number-in-angular-or-typescript/

Comment: please try this way {{((((parseFloat(greyDemandPrice)*parseFloat(orderedProduct.ExchangeRateBDT))/parseFloat(orderQuanity)))+parseFloat(orderedProduct.EffectiveWeavingCharge))}} If this wouldn't give you result . better put a debug point on console and see them.

Comment: I am able to solve the problem. I am trying to do it on view. In this time I am doing in controller. Now it's working fine. Thanks a lot how try to help me.

Comment: thats why I said "also convert to numbers before sending to template"