# javascript date is wrong format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that gets a date from a jQuery calendar and then formats it in year-month-day.

The date I get for the calendar is 03/04/2013 for dateString and then I want it in the format of 2013-03-04. But the date I am getting for start_date is 2013-21-04. Strange because it had been ok, I think.

```
function makeUpDates() {
    // concantenate values to date_start and date_end hidden inputs
    var dateString = document.getElementById('date').value, date = new Date(dateString);
    document.getElementById('date_start').value = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var numDays = document.getElementById('slider').value;
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(numDays));
    var dateEnd = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    document.getElementById('date_end').value = dateEnd;
}
```

Comment: That's not the code you got this result from, is it?

Comment: [Always specify the radix when you use parseInt()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611824/why-do-we-need-to-use-radix) (e.g. `parseInt(numDays,10)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the dates like this

```
//will take a date in the form MM/DD/YYYY and return YYYY-MM-DD
function convertDate(dateString){
    var dateparts = dateString.split("/");
    var newDate = dateparts[2]+"-"+dateparts[0]+"-"+dateparts[1]
    return newDate;
}
```

Also for more general Date handling you can check out moment.js, mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10119138/1424361) to a more general question on this topic

Answer (score 1):

> start_date is 2013-21-04

Probably you forgot the parenthesis around `date.getMonth()+1` in the string concatenation, yielding `21` instead of `3`. It seems to be fixed in the snippet you posted though.