# Why is the '+' operator concating my numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, operators

I want to access the values entered in the input box and then get their sum, but javascript is concatenating the result. Here is the code

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
     $( "#dateSelector" ).click(function(){ 
    $(this).datepicker();
     });
   });

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ocb750cb").click(function(){
      var closingBal = 0;
    var openingBal = document.getElementById("ocb750ob").value;
    alert(openingBal);
    Number(openingBal);
    var stockBal =  document.getElementById("ocb750sb").value;
    alert(stockBal);
    Number(stockBal);
    var sold = document.getElementById("ocb750sl").value; 
    alert(sold);
    var store = document.getElementById("ocb750cb");
        store.value = (stockBal + openingBal) - sold;
    });



 });



</script>



<th class = "main brand">OCB 750</th>
<th class = "main"><input type="text" maxlength="5" id="ocb750ob"></th>
<th class = "main"><input type="text" maxlength="5" id="ocb750sb"></th>
<th class = "main"><input type="text" maxlength="5" id="ocb750tl"></th>
<th class = "main"><input type="text" maxlength="5" id="ocb750sl"></th>
<th class = "main"><input type="text" maxlength="5" id="ocb750rs"></th>
<th class = "main"><input type="text" maxlength="5" id="ocb750cb"></th>
```

suppose i enter 5 and 2 my output will be 52 and not 7, it is getting concatenated

Comment: `value` returns a string, `+` concatenates strings. `+value` should do.

Comment: Since *all* of the answers so far managed to get this wrong, I 'll say it here: **you have to specify the radix (second argument) when using `parseInt`**. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611824/why-do-we-need-to-use-radix

Comment: You should really check out http://try.jquery.com. Also some of your HTML isn't valid. `<th class = "main" class = "brand".../>` should be `<th class="main brand".../>`. Equally, you probably don't need to put that class on all of your `th` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You values have string format,you need use [parceInt](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert2.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The value of a textbox is text. You need to cast it to a number:

```
var openingBal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ocb750ob").value);
```

Comment: Shit, I knew it, I simply asked without doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use parseInt(x) to be sure, that value is interpreted as integer. Otherwise javascript interpret it as string, so + operator is concatenating.

Use:

```
 var openingBal = parseInt(document.getElementById("ocb750ob").value);
```

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var stockBal =  document.getElementById("ocb750sb").value;
```

stockbal will be a string, so you have to parse it to get an integer

```
   try{
      var stockBalInt = parseInt(stockBal);
   }catch(error){
    -..handle error
   }
```

Since you concatenate two strings together, "5" + "2" = "52"

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
store.value = ( parseInt(stockBal) + parseInt(openingBal) ) - parseInt(sold);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because all the variables retrieved using getElementById("id").value are "string". Try to do like this:

```
var sold = parseInt(document.getElementById("id").value);
```

Hope this will help.