# .each( ) Function Not Producing Unique Values

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-animate, each

I have a bunch of blocks that I'm trying to have move along a square 'track', like a train.

```
    var itemLoop = function(){
        $("li").each(function(getLeft, getTop) {
            getLeft = parseInt($(this).css('left'));
            getTop = parseInt($(this).css('top'));

            if (getTop > 0 && getLeft < 5) {
                $(this).css('top', (getTop - 5 ) + "px");
            } else if (getTop > 140) {
                $(this).css('left', (getLeft - 5) + "px");
            } else if (getLeft > 140) {
                $(this).css('top', (getTop + 5 ) + "px");
            } else {
                $(this).css('left', (getLeft + 5 ) + "px");
            }
        });
    }

setInterval(itemLoop, 100);
```

However, for the above, the blocks don't snake around the corners, but stay stuck together.

I thought maybe it was because the same getTop/Left value is being used for all the lis, but I'm not sure how else I could script this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [position() function](http://api.jquery.com/position/) rather than the css function. So instead of this:

```
getLeft = parseInt($(this).css('left'));
getTop = parseInt($(this).css('top'));
```

Do this:

```
var pos = $(this).position();

getLeft = parseInt(pos.left);
getTop = parseInt(pos.top);
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/judeosborn/rd2Ky/

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to add the radix parameter to parseInt. So it should look more like getLeft = parseInt(pos.left, 10); Here's why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611824/why-do-we-need-to-use-radix