# Javascript giving NaN error

Tags: javascript

I am using the below codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function minus(){
var t=document.getElementById("totalcost").value;
var u=document.getElementById("advpay").value;  
var set=(t-u);
document.getElementById("textfield").value=set;
return true;
}
</script>
```

I entered **"6000"** as value in **totalcost id field** and **"1000"** in **advpay id field**. so in **textfield id** field, it should show ***5000 (6000-1000)***, but it is giving answer as ***NaN***. where is the error ?

Answer (score 5):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function minus() {
    var t = parseInt(document.getElementById("totalcost").value, 10),
        u = parseInt(document.getElementById("advpay").value, 10),
        set = (t - u);
    document.getElementById("textfield").value = set;
    return true;
}
</script>
```

This is happening because you are trying to subtract two strings! `value` returns the string of the input, you need to parse it to a number in order to subtract them. Remember to specify radix of `parseInt`, otherwise the number could be parsed not as a decimal. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611824/why-do-we-need-to-use-radix) for more detailed informations.

Comment: "Remember to specify radix of parseInt, otherwise the number will be parsed as an octal." I don't think so...

Comment: You are right, it will not be parsed as an octal, it will be parsed basically on the number itself.

Comment: "_... otherwise the number will be parsed as an octal_ **IF it begins with a zero.**"

Comment: You commented now, I have modified the answer 15 minutes ago... Is the update wrong?

Comment: No, your correction is good.  My comment was just meant to clarify _when_ numbers _can_ get interpretted as octals.

Answer (score 0):

NaN is abbreviated of Not a Number. NaN will be the result of any calculation which contains anything rather than a number (strings, boolean, object). In your case the calculations were made by using 2 strings, That's why it has returned NaN. You have to cast your values into number before doing the calculation.

You can cast your values by using the following piece of code:

Example 1:

```
 var t = +document.getElementById("totalcost").value;
 u = +document.getElementById("advpay").value;
```

Example 2 (As @LightStyle suggested):

```
 var t = parseInt(document.getElementById("totalcost").value, 10),
 u = parseInt(document.getElementById("advpay").value, 10),
```