# jquery character countdown in textarea

Tags: jquery

I want to provide a visual to show users how many of the characters remain in a textarea as they type in their response. My code below WORKS! but I kinda pieced the logic together and have A LOT of repetition. Is there a better way to write the jquery below that is more maintainable and succinct?

HTML

```
<td colspan="4" style="text-align:center;">
     NOTES<br>
     <textarea class="sam_notes maxed" maxlength="750" name="sam_notes" style="height:100px;width:90%;margin:0 auto;"></textarea>
     <br>
     <span style="font:normal 11px sans-serif;color:#B00400;">
         <span class='counter_msg'></span>
     </span>
</td>
```

JQUERY

```
(function() {
     $(document).on('focus', '.sam_notes', function(e){
      var msgSpan = $(this).parents('td').find('.counter_msg');
      var ml     = parseInt( $(this).attr('maxlength') );
      var length = $(this).val().length;
      var msg = ml - length + ' characters of ' + ml + ' characters left';

      msgSpan.empty().html(msg);
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', '.sam_notes', function(e){
      var msgSpan = $(this).parents('td').find('.counter_msg');
      var ml     = parseInt( $(this).attr('maxlength') );
      var length = $(this).val().length;
      var msg = ml - length + ' characters of ' + ml + ' characters left';

      msgSpan.empty().html(msg);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Why don't you make use of any plugin such as this one: http://cssglobe.com/lab/charcount/01.html

Comment: Because if we all use plugins for everything, nobody will know how to code any more. I know what you mean, but for simple things I don't see why a plugin is always the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way :

```
$('td').on('focus keypress', '.sam_notes', function (e) {

    var $this = $(this);
    var msgSpan = $this.parents('td').find('.counter_msg');
    var ml = parseInt($this.attr('maxlength'), 10);
    var length = this.value.length;
    var msg = ml - length + ' characters of ' + ml + ' characters left';

    msgSpan.html(msg);
});
```

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/8gKs4/2/

Here's what I've changed in line order:

1. removed `document` and changed it to `td`. This way the event wont bubble upto parent.
2. Changed `keyup` to `keypress`. `keyup` wont work if you the user doesnt remove his finger from the keyboard. `keypress` captures `keyup` and `keydown`.
3. since you're having the same stuff in `focus` and `keypress`, why not join them?
4. you're using `$(this)` two times, so cached it for reuse later. (I know..I know.. I'm nitpicking)
5. Added a radix to `parseInt`, which is a JSLINT rule. A radix is the extra number which you add to `parseInt`. [Look at this answer for more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611824/why-do-we-need-to-use-radix)
6. Changed `$(this).val()` to `this.value`, which is more native.
7. removed `empty()`. Since you're already using `html()`, this is not needed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I added a screenshot of your answer to my iPhone because your explanation of what you did (rather than just providing the demo ) teaches me best practices and will make me a better developer. Now I just have to figure out what a "radix" is since I figured it is NOT a spicy, red vegatable.

Comment: That was where I first saw radix ... I am googling it now to find out what it is  (I guess that explains why I hadn't used one before, eh? LOL )

Comment: Once I refreshed the page, I saw your edit and link to the radix explanation ... MUCH APPRECIATED!

Comment: Nice, but beware of these two modest shortcomings: (1) if characters are deleted, the "max remaining" number does not correspondingly increase; and (2) pasted characters do not count against the maximum.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there are other improvements you could make, but the most obvious one to me is:

### Refactor out the update count logic to prevent duplication

```
(function() {
     $(document).on('focus', '.sam_notes', function(e){
      UpdateCount($(this));
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', '.sam_notes', function(e){
      UpdateCount($(this));
    });

    function UpdateCount(notes) {
      var msgSpan = notes.parents('td').find('.counter_msg');
      var ml     = parseInt( notes.attr('maxlength') );
      var length = notes.val().length;
      var msg = ml - length + ' characters of ' + ml + ' characters left';

      msgSpan.html(msg);
    }
})();
```

### Also, you don't need to empty() before html()

`msgSpan.empty().html(msg);` is the same as `msgSpan.html(msg);`

Comment: I KNEW there was a better way!

Comment: Thanks to you, I now know how to pass the $(this) to a function. That in itself will make my jQuery code SOOO much better since I won't have to next anonymous functions within anonymous functions like I used to. I gave you a +1 but had to choose another answer as the answer since that was the code I decided to use. Again THANK YOU for your time!!!

Answer (score 1):

i had a look at this:
http://www.scriptiny.com/2012/09/jquery-input-textarea-limiter/
then extended it to a jquery widget.
yes, i know it is totally over-engineered.  I just did it to learn more about widgets.
but on the plus side, it is super simple to use.  just call the widget on a text area with:

```
$(selector).limiter();
```

there are a bunch of parameters, you can send thru options as object, eg;

```
 $(selector).limiter({maxChars:1000,warningChars:990});
```

note, you can add the class stylings in your css.  i assume here you have the jqueryui css installed for the warning text to change colour when it his the warningChars value.  something like
.ui-limiter-chars {position: absolute;padding-left: 1em;}
could do the trick...

have a look at the fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/DE5m9/2/

```
$.widget("ui.limiter", {
    options:{
        limiterClass:'ui-limiter-chars ui-widget-content',
        limiterTag:'small',
        maxChars:100,
        warningClass:'ui-state-error-text',
        warningChars:90,
        wrapperClass:'ui-limiter-wrapper ui-widget',
        tagName:'TEXTAREA'
    },
    _create: function(){
        // make sure that the widget can only be called once and it is only called on textareas
        var o = this.options;
        if (($(this).attr('aria-owns') === undefined ) && (this.element[0].tagName === o.tagName)) {
            var self = this;
            var id = Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 10).replace(/(:|\.)/g, '');
            // ids = array of id of textarea, wrapper, and limiter chars ids.
            this.ids = [(this.element.attr('id') || 'ui-limiter-' + id),'ui-limiter-wrapper-'+id,'ui-limiter-chars-'+id];
            this.element[0].id = this.ids[0];
            var limiterWrapper = $('<div/>',{
                'class':o.wrapperClass,
                'id':this.ids[1]
            });
            // semantically, this seems to be a good fit for a small tag. ie not important.
            var limiterChars = $('<'+o.limiterTag+'/>', {
                'class': o.limiterClass,
                'id': this.ids[2]
            });

            $('#'+this.ids[0]).wrap(limiterWrapper);
            $('#'+this.ids[0]).after(limiterChars);
            $('#'+this.ids[0]).attr('aria-owns',this.ids[2]);
            $('#'+this.ids[0]).on("keyup focus", function() {
                self._setCount($('#'+self.ids[0]), $('#'+self.ids[2]));
            });
            this._setCount($('#'+this.ids[0]), $('#'+this.ids[2]));
        }
    },
    _setCount:function (src, elem) {
        var o = this.options;
        var chars = src.val().length;
        if (chars > o.maxChars) {
            src.val(src.val().substr(0, o.maxChars));
            chars = o.maxChars;
        }
        $('#'+this.ids[2]).text(o.maxChars - chars );
        if (chars > o.warningChars)
        {
            $('#'+this.ids[2]).addClass(o.warningClass);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#'+this.ids[2]).removeClass(o.warningClass);
        }
    },
    destroy: function(){
        $('#'+this.ids[2]).remove();
        $('#'+this.ids[0]).unwrap();
        $('#'+this.ids[0]).removeAttr('aria-owns');
        $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
    },

});
```

Comment: What i like about this and which the other examples don't have is when you delete, the counter goes back up