# How to get numeric value from a prompt box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to do some simple mathematical calculations in HTML and jQuery and JavaScript, so I wanted to get input from user.
For input I tried doing this :

```
var x = prompt("Enter a Value","0");
var y = prompt("Enter a Value", "0");
```

But I am not able to perform any kind of calculations as these values are strings.
Please, can any one show me how to convert them into integers.

Comment: Use [`Number`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) to convert strings to numbers. [`parseFloat`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) can be used when you need to _parse_ numbers from a string — the semantics of _parsing_ and _converting_ are different; read the docs to understand the difference. If you really need integers, use [`parseInt`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), but please [_with_ the second parameter, `10`](/q/16880327/4642212).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**parseInt()** or **parseFloat()** are functions in JavaScript which can help you convert the values into integers or floats respectively.

#### Syntax:

```
 parseInt(string, radix);
 parseFloat(string);
```

- **string**: the string expression to be parsed as a number.
- **radix**: (optional, but highly encouraged) the base of the numeral system to be used - a number between 2 and 36.

#### Example:

```
 var x = prompt("Enter a Value", "0");
 var y = prompt("Enter a Value", "0");
 var num1 = parseInt(x);
 var num2 = parseInt(y);
```

After this you can perform which ever calculations you want on them.

Comment: -1 for the following reasons: parseFloat() does not have second argument (read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), omitting radix in parseInt is a bad practice (see explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and finally: conversion is not necessary to perform calculations (JavaScript is weakly typed, proof: http://jsfiddle.net/ehhfE/).

Comment: @Kadima, I reverted part of your proposed edit: the second argument to the *prompt* function is not the radix, but the default value.

Comment: @trincot Yep, you're right. Sorry, been staring at a computer screen too long.

Answer (score 12):

JavaScript will "convert" numeric string to integer, if you perform calculations on it (as JS is weakly typed). But you can convert it yourself using `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.

Just remember to put radix in `parseInt`!

In case of integer inputs:

```
var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter a Value", "0"), 10);
var y = parseInt(prompt("Enter a Value", "0"), 10);
```

In case of float:

```
var x = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a Value", "0"));
var y = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a Value", "0"));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var xInt = parseInt(x)
```

This will return either the `integer` value, or `NaN`.

Read more about [parseInt here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `parseInt()` but, as mentioned, the radix (base) should be specified:

```
x = parseInt(x, 10);
y = parseInt(y, 10);
```

10 means a base-10 number.

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611824/why-do-we-need-to-use-radix) for an explanation of why the radix is necessary.

Comment: Now it is okay (with radix disclaimer added).

Comment: Thank you @Tadeck +1, I'd forgotten it momentarily ;)

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Demo**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_parseint) [**Reading more Info**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

`parseInt(x)` it will cast it into integer

```
x = parseInt(x);
x = parseInt(x,10); //the radix is 10 (decimal)
```

`parseFloat(x)` it will cast it into float

[**Working Demo**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_parsefloat) [**Reading more Info**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp)

```
x = parseFloat(x);
```

you can directly use `prompt`

```
var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter a Number", "1"), 10)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use parseInt() to convert

For eg.

```
var z = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
```

use parseFloat() if you want to handle float value.

Comment: You should always specify the radix when using `parseInt` (see answer by Andy G)