# JavaScript NaN error loop

Tags: javascript

I am receiving a `NaN` error when I run this code. I've been trying to find out why for a while now and can't for the life of me.

To clarify, I am trying to receive;

- the total amount owed by customers
- how many customers are entered

  ```
  function Summarise()
  {

      ID = prompt("Enter a Customer ID number ", -1)

      while(ID != -1) 
      {
          var gasUsed = 0
          var total = 0
          gasUsed = prompt("Enter amount of gas used ", "0")
          ///Standard Rate is used to assist in the calculation of customers in excess of 60 Gas Used
          StandardRate = 60 * 1.75

          if(gasUsed <= 60) 
          {
              total= gasUsed * 2
              document.write("Customers ID: " + ID)
              document.write(" has gas usage of " + gasUsed)
              document.write(" and owes $" + total)
              document.write("<br/>")
          } 
          else 
          {
              total= (gasUsed - 60) * 1.50 + StandardRate
              document.write("Customers ID: " + ID)
              document.write(" has gas usage of " + gasUsed)
              document.write(" and owes $" + total)
              document.write("<br/>")

          }

          var totalowed = total + totalowed
          var totalcustomers = ++totalcustomers

          ID = prompt("Enter a Customer ID number ", -1)

      }

      document.write("Total amount owed $" + totalowed)
      document.write("<br/>")
      document.write("Total Number of customers:" + totalcustomers)


  }
  ```

Comment: This is because you are using some variable that is undefined and providing undefined value..

Comment: Quick tip: semi-colons are NOT (really) optional.

Comment: Im still very very new to JavaScript, can you explain a little more @ DeDevelopers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define these two variables before the loop:

```
var totalowed = 0;
var totalcustomers = 0;
```

they were initially undefined when you were assigning values to them, this always create problems.

You can see the working snippet below:

```js
function Summarise() {

ID = prompt("Enter a Customer ID number ", -1)
var totalowed = 0;
var totalcustomers = 0;
while(ID != -1) 
{
    var gasUsed = 0;
    var total = 0;
    gasUsed = prompt("Enter amount of gas used ", "0");
    ///Standard Rate is used to assist in the calculation of customers in excess of 60 Gas Used
    StandardRate = 60 * 1.75

    if(gasUsed <= 60) 
    {
        total = gasUsed * 2;
        document.write("Customers ID: " + ID);
        document.write(" has gas usage of " + gasUsed);
        document.write(" and owes $" + total);
        document.write("<br/>");
    } 
    else 
    {
        total= (gasUsed - 60) * 1.50 + StandardRate;
        document.write("Customers ID: " + ID);
        document.write(" has gas usage of " + gasUsed);
        document.write(" and owes $" + total);
        document.write("<br/>");

    }

    totalowed = total + totalowed;
    totalcustomers = ++totalcustomers;
    ID = prompt("Enter a Customer ID number ", -1);

}

document.write("Total amount owed $" + totalowed);
document.write("<br/>")
document.write("Total Number of customers:" + totalcustomers);
}

Summarise();
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, I see what you mean. Silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

totalowed and totalcustomers are declared in the while loop and thus not available outside it. You will need to define them outside the while loop.

Answer (score -1):

You are not converting the string from the prompt into an integer.  See here:

You can use:

```
ID = parseInt(prompt("Enter a Customer ID number ", -1), 10);
```

Remember to provide a radix value to the `parseInt` function for completeness.

[How to get numeric value from a prompt box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907455/how-to-get-numeric-value-from-a-prompt-box)