# Getting NaN error as the result

Tags: javascript, nan

I seem to be getting a NaN error as the result in my JavaScript code.

I'm pretty new to this, would appreciate any help.

Solved by giving value to the total var.

Comment: Can you please explain what actually you are trying to do?

Comment: NaN @MagnusEngdal. He does say.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get numeric value from a prompt box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907455/how-to-get-numeric-value-from-a-prompt-box)

Comment: Just initialize your `total` to `0`. So that when you do a `total +=` then `total` has something to add to.

Comment: At least 3 different issues then, maybe try [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: You don't need to edit the question after you have got the answer. Pls revert your last edit, so that others can get any similar help. (We all know that your problem is solved, after you have accepted an answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

- You should use `parseFloat` instead of using strings.
- You should initialize `total` (this is what causes the `nan`)
- You should initialize arrays properly.

---

```
function tax() {
    var price = new Array(10);
    var quant = new Array(10);
    var taxam = 18;
    var total = 0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        quant[i] = parseFloat(prompt("Insert Quantity: "));
        price[i] = parseFloat(prompt("Insert Price: "));
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        total += price[i] * quant[i];
    }
    total = total * (taxam / 100);
    alert(total);
}
```

Comment: Well, `"10" * "10"` is still `100`, multiplying numeric strings make perfect sense.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks that's a js quirk I wasn't aware of, I think he's problem is not initializing `total`. Do you happen to know if this quirk exists in strict mode?

Comment: @Normal_Dude_LearnsCode No problems you can accept it if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I guess with this `var price = [10]` you were trying to create an array with 10 numbers, but that is not the way it works in Javascript `var price = [10]` will give you an array with 10 at the 0th position. The only other tweak I would make there is make `var price = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` to actually achieve what you set out for initally

Comment: Or `var price = new Array(10);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, JavaScript is not Java ;)

You seem to try to initialize your arrays with a length of 10. This works in Java but in Javascript an array is dynamic and writing :

```
myArray = [10];
```

will just set the value `10` in the first index of the array.

Then, as you prompt the user to input numbers, the numbers will be interpreted as a string.
So it would be good to cast it to a number before working with it.
To cast it :

```
var value = '10000';
valueAsInt = parseFloat('10000',10);
//or simply 
valueAsInt = +value;
```

Now we come to your problem, as `total` is not initialised, the first affectation will be

```
undefined += n;
```

this will give a `NaN`.

So just initialise `total` before using it :

```
var total = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize total variable first because it is undefined initially

```
var total = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to parse the String variables to a Number:

```
function tax() {

var price = [10];
var quant = [10];
var taxam = 18;
var total = 0;

 for(i=0;i<10;i++) {

    quant[i] = Number(prompt("Insert Quantity: "));

    price[i] = Number(prompt("Insert Price: "));

    }

for(i=0;i<10;i++) {

total += price[i] * quant[i];

 }

total = total * (taxam / 100);

alert(total);


}
tax()
```