# How to pass JavaScript variable to jQuery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a variable to an jquery ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            // get page number
            var page = parseInt(getUrlParameter('page'));
            if (page < 1) page = 1;
            var page_next = page + 1;

          $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: { 
                    page: page,

                },  
                dataType: 'json', 
           ...
```

unfortunatelly the variable "page" seems not to be present inside the ajax request. Doing an cosole.log(page); inside reveils "NaN" as a value.

The problem seems to be

```
if (page < 1) page = 1;
```

If this value retrieved via get is not present, then page will be NoN.

How can I make sure page is always defined as minimum 1 ?

Comment: the approach is absolutely correct, the error is probably in the function `getUrlParameter('page')`, which is NOT returning a valid response (or not a number or anything that can be converted to such). Can you please show us that function?

Comment: The only problem with the approach, from the code you've shared so far, is that [you don't have a radix on parseInt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611824/why-do-we-need-to-use-radix), but that wouldn't cause this issue. Whatever `getUrlParameter` is returning is, as briosheje said, not something that can be converted to a number, hence: NaN: Not a Number

Comment: the problem seems to be with getURLParameter function as the guys above have pointed out. try with var page = 1; and see if variable contains value 1.

Comment: Just narrowed the error down. The problem is within: if (page < 1) page = 1; This does not seem to work if there is no get parameter "page". Will edit question now.

Comment: @merlin please check my answer, I've suggested a validation in order to default the page to 1 if you get a Nan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getUrlParameter` is returning something that is not convertible to a number `NaN = Not a Number`, if you share that function maybe we can debug a little bit further the root cause of your issue, in the meantime, I suggest the following validation:

```
var page = parseInt(getUrlParameter('page'));
if (page < 1 || isNaN(page)) page = 1;
var page_next = page + 1;
```

That way if your page is not a number, you default it to page 1.
Hope this clears things out and helps you.

Comment: That's fine, but I would rather say that he should fix the getUrlParameter instead of its result. I mean, the result should already be a number, so he should assert that in the **function** rather than after it, especially from the moment that we have no idea of how / where he is taking such data from, right?

Comment: Thats why i've edited my question. If He does not share the function there is no way to find the root cause, so I've only made a suggestion in order to make the code more robust. If a user types anything in the url other than a number, it would be nice that the application loads page 1 instead of crashing or displaying an error.

Comment: This leads in the right direction. Works if I leave parseInt inside. If I remove it, the page+1 reveals 11 instead of 2.

Comment: You should leave parseInt in order to make it more robust. And the condition i've wrote is a safe check to default the page to 1 if the user types anything other than a number in the url.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is within the if statement, the fastest solution I can think about (despite I don't approve it) is this one:

Replace :

```
var page = parseInt(getUrlParameter('page'));
```

with:

```
var page = +getUrlParameter("page") || 1;
```

if page is falsey (NaN is falsey) it will set it to 1, else to its result.

Example with fiddle:

```
function getUrlParameter ( param ) {
    return param === "page" ? 5 : false;
}

var page = +getUrlParameter("hello") || 1;
alert(page);

page = +getUrlParameter("page") || 1;
alert(page);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/51tvdsve/

In any case, you should rather try to fix your getUrlParameter function instead of trying to avoid its output, but that's just my opinion.