# If doesnt work in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The If always gives me the last result

check this snippet

```js
function calc(on, ep, am, ek, b1, b2, b3, b4) {
  var sum, mo;
  b1 = parseInt(b1);
  b2 = parseInt(b2);
  b3 = parseInt(b3);
  b4 = parseInt(b4);
  sum = b1 + b2 + b3 + b4;
  mo = sum / 4;
  if (mo < 5) {
    x = "Not Good";
  }
  if (mo < 6, 5 && mo > 4, 99) {
    x = "Good";
  }
  if (mo < 8, 5 && mo > 6, 49) {
    x = "Really Good";
  }
  if (mo > 8, 49) {
    x = "Perfect";
  }
  alert("O " + on + " " + ep + " " + am + " who is in " + ek + "th semester had avereged " + mo + " " + x);
}
```

I cant get it to work with else if or something like that but I need it to work however it is

Comment: [Don't use parseInt without a radix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611824/why-do-we-need-to-use-radix).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript [floating point literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Floating-point_literals) use a `.` character (U+002E : FULL STOP) as a decimal point, not a `,` character (U+002C : COMMA) (which is a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)).

Answer (score 0):

As already said you have to use `.` and not `,`. Your `mo < 6,5 && mo > 4,99` will always evaluate to `99` which is truthy. So it does not matter what value the `mo` has.

```js
var mo = 10;
console.log( (mo < 6,5 && mo > 4,99) );
```

See [MDN: Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) for more informations:

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.