# Jquery change number inside element but keep the rest

Tags: jquery

How can I do that? Right now it does increase the number, which it should but removes "tykkäykset"

```
<span class="amount">3 tykkäykset</span>

var num = parseInt($.trim($('.amount').html()));
$('.amount').html(++num);
```

I'm a complete novice

Comment: is "tykkäykset" a fixed string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating a element for the amount and change the value in there:

```
<span class="my-amount"><span class="amount">3</span> tykkäykset</span>

var num = parseInt($.trim($('.amount').html()));
$('.amount').html(++num);
```

Comment: I would also use `text()` and provide the [radix for `parseInt`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6611854/11683).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var text = $.trim($('.amount').html());
var res = text.split(" "); 
var num = parseInt(res[0]) + 1;
text = num + " "+ res[1];
$('.amount').html(text);
```

However, i would also recommend Philipp Sander response.