# Why am i getting NaN error?

Tags: javascript, nan

I have a program that reads a specific text file from a coding challenge that I've recieved and it takes the numbers and puts it into an array for me to solve a quadratic equation. When I go to display my answers I keep getting the NaN error on all of my values and I cant find where I messed up.

### CODE

```
var lines = data[0].split("/n");
var numQuads = lines[0];
for (var i = 1; i < numQuads; i++){
  var fields = lines[i].split(",");
  var a = fields[0];
  var b = fields[1];
  var c = fields[2];
}
a = parseInt();
b = parseInt();
c = parseInt();
var discr = (b * b) - (4 * (a * c));
var sqrDiscr = Math.sqrt(discr);
var x = (-b + sqrDiscr) / (2*a);
var y = (-b - sqrDiscr) / (2*a);
var outputL = "The quadratic equation with coefficients A = " + a + " B = " + b + " C= " + c + " has no real roots!";
var outputW = "The quadratic equation with coefficients A = " + a + " B = " + b + " C= " + c + " has roots x = " + x + " and x = " + y;
if (discr >= 0) {
  output += outputW + "\n";
}
else {
  output += outputL + "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: You have `a = parseInt();` - you need `a = parseFloat(a);`

Comment: `parseInt` is a function that takes a string as a parameter and returns an integer. When you call it as `parseInt()` with no arguments, it’s not doing anything useful.

Comment: You didn't declared the array `data`.

Comment: I declared the data array further up in my code but even with the parseFloat im still getting the NaN error

Comment: @MasonGarrett, then you didn't declared the variable `output`.

Comment: You should always provide the minimal code so we can check it and see where the errors are.

Comment: My teacher has it set up so i use this template to display my answers so I have the output variable already setup as well as the data array setup above. The array was working to simply display the text file in the output but when I started to add the loop it gave me the NaN

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide an argument to the [`parseInt`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) function. It works like this: `parseInt("2")` for example. You probably want to use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`.

Another remark: your `data` array is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you have insert String in parseInt()

```
a = parseInt("67");
b = parseInt("3");
c = parseInt("2");
```

Comment: It is advised to never use `parseInt` without the second (base) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Should probably be:

```
a = parseInt(a);
b = parseInt(b);
c = parseInt(c);
```

Comment: It is advised to never use `parseInt` without the second (base) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not parsing anything with your parse int. 
Take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) for some docs on parseInt.
Anyway that's how it should look like in your code:

```
a = parseInt(a, 10);
b = parseInt(b, 10);
c = parseInt(c, 10);
d = parseInt(d, 10);
```

EDIT: following the suggestion of @d3l I looked into the parseInt parameters, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611824/why-do-we-need-to-use-radix) question there could be some unexpected behaviours of the parseInt function without adding the radix parameter. Hence I added it to my solution.

Assuming you are parsing integers we can specify 10 as base.

Comment: It is advised to never use `parseInt` without the second (base) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was `var lines = data[0].split("/n");`
I used the wrong character. It was supposed to be `var lines = data[0].split("\n");`