# Why does badge count go from 1 to 12?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When receiving a message in my chat program, count should increment by 1. 
But it jumps from 1 to 12.
Why is that?

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
  var count = Number($('.badge').text());
  $('.badge').text(count + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="badge">0</span>

<button id="btn"></button>
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] – if you click on the "Run code snippet" button, it shows "0", not 12.

Comment: Your code works here. In chrome at least.

Comment: @yogendarji the code already works and count is already a number

Comment: Don't forget the radix: `$('.badge').text(parseInt(count, 10) + 1);` for older clients, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611824/why-do-we-need-to-use-radix

Comment: Convert to int `$('.badge').text(parseInt(count) + 1);`

Comment: @Blaise @Feras Al Sous `Number()` works just as well as `parseInt()` for this purpose, that is not the issue here.

Comment: I have updated with more code. Sorry for the minimal snippet. I don't get it thought.. the snippet works, but my program doesn't

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your problem by putting *two* elements with class `badge` in the same page. This causes `$('.badge').text()` to return `11`, which is then incremented to `12` which is stored in each badge. If you only intended to have one badge, just get rid of the other one. Or perhaps you meant to give them each different names?

Otherwise, you could increment each badge separately:

```
$(".badge").each(function(idx){
    var count = Number($(this).text());
    $(this).text(count + 1);
});
```

Comment: actually I have two .badge... So I guess it would be better to call them id="badge1" and id="badge2"?