# javascript doesn't return the desired value

Tags: javascript

I try to implement the following simple equation `(5+x=?)` using html and JavaScript:

```js
function count() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  document.getElementById('execute').innerHTML = x + 5;
}
```

```html
<div> 5 + <input type="number" id="myInput">
  <input type="button" value="=" onclick="count()">
  <span id="execute">?</span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately when I write for example 2 in the input field and then click on the button `(=)` it gives me as answer the number 52, instead of the answer that I would like to see – 7.

It seems that it just joins the new number next to 5, instead of adding it, like it is a string and not a number. I know it’s not the brightest function and it’s not very useful, but I will appreciate if you could give me a hint where I am wrong.

This will help me understand better JavaScript and continue my education.

Comment: `.value`s always return strings. Cast it to a number first, or `+` will concatenate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help. Thank you.

```js
    function count()
    {var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
        document.getElementById('execute').innerHTML = parseInt(x) + 5;}
```

```html
<div> 5 + <input type="number" id="myInput">
    <input type="button" value="=" onclick="count()">
    <span id="execute">?</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: You don't know if it'll be an integer. `Number` is better.

Answer (score -2):

Several ways to change a string to a number, for this example I use `parseInt()` with 10 for the radix.

```js
function count() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var xn = parseInt(x,10);
  document.getElementById('execute').innerHTML = xn + 5;
}
```

```html
<div> 5 + <input type="number" id="myInput">
  <input type="button" value="=" onclick="count()">
  <span id="execute">?</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please choose to close answer as dupe

Comment: @Rajesh this answer does differ from the other even if it is subtle.

Comment: Note: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6611870/125981  (not directly applicable due to the `type` on the input but also noted in my answer.  I still stand by this given the "learning" comment from the OP.