# Adding 1 to a css style property in Javascript

Tags: javascript, addition

I am trying to first get the value of the order property of an element, and then adding 1 to it when I click a button. Thing is, instead of getting 1 and adding 1 and getting 2, I get 11. Shouldn't the "+=" operator add the values? What am I doing wrong?

```
carouselPrev.addEventListener("click", function(){

  const firstPost = document.querySelector(".blog-post");

  let firstPostOrder = firstPost.style.getPropertyValue('order');

  firstPost.style.order = firstPostOrder += 1;
});
```

Comment: You need to treat `firstPostOrder` as an integer using `parseInt()` before doing arithmetic. Otherwise, you're just appending `1` to a string.

Answer (score 7):

Css properties are strings, and `'1' + 1 = 11`.

Add "+" before `firstPostOrder` to convert it to a number.

`firstPost.style.order = +firstPostOrder += 1;`

Comment: That did work thank you. Accepting when it allows me to.

Answer (score 2):

the values are strings so they are be concatenated, try parsing to an integer before using parseInt()

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
carouselPrev.addEventListener("click", function(){

const firstPost = document.querySelector(".blog-post");

let firstPostOrder = firstPost.style.getPropertyValue('order');

firstPost.style.order = parseInt(firstPostOrder,10) +1;
});
```

Comment: Always suggest `radix` with `parseInt` i.e. `parseInt(firstPostOrder, 10)` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611824/why-do-we-need-to-use-radix

Comment: That is just not working. The order is not changing at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, the "+=" operator is an assignment operator you'd use in lieu of "=".

```
let x = 42;
x += 1;
```

is equivalent to

```
let x = 42;
x = x + 1;
```

You want to use just the "+" to add the values, not the "+=".