# JavaScript query about ParseInt

Tags: javascript

Could anyone explain why the result is 5?

```
console.log(parseInt('101', 2)); // 5
```

Comment: Because the second param is a radix, and the number 2 makes the parse interpret as binary number.

More about that you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611824/why-do-we-need-to-use-radix-parameter-when-calling-parseint

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 4):

The second argument to [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) specifies the number base.

Base 2 is [binary](https://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-number-system.html).

101 in binary is (`1*4 + 0*2 + 1*1 =`) 5 in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument you are passing to parseInt function is called Radix.

When you are passing 2 means that the string is in binary so the binary of 5 is 101.

5 (Decimal) = 101 (Binary)

That is why you are getting 5 as int.