# joinedAtTimeStamp is showing Nan discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was coding a `userInfo` command but when I use the command, the `joinedAtTimeStamp` is showing `<t:NaN:R>` in the embed. It's the only problem in this code.

My code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed, ContextMenuInteraction } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "userInfo",
    aliases: ["user"],
    permissions: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "ATTACH_FILES"],
    description: "user",

    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord, profileData) {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(!args[0]) {
            const response2 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setAuthor({name: message.author.tag, iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true})})
            .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
            .addFields(
                {name: "ID", value: message.author.id},
                {name: "Joined Server", value: `<t:${parseInt(message.author.joinedTimestamp / 1000)}:R>`, inline: true},
                {name: "Account Created", value: `<t:${parseInt(message.author.createdTimestamp / 1000)}:R>`, inline: true},
                
            );
            message.reply({embeds:[response2]});
        }
        const response = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setAuthor({name: target.tag, iconURL: target.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true})})
            .setThumbnail(target.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
            .addFields(
                {name: "ID", value: target.id},
                {name: "Joined Server", value: `<t:${parseInt(target.joinedTimestamp / 1000)}:R>`, inline: true},
                {name: "Account Created", value: `<t:${parseInt(target.createdTimestamp / 1000)}:R>`, inline: true},
            );
            
        message.reply({embeds: [response], ephemeral: true})
    }
}
```

I am using discord.js v13 and node 16.

Comment: Could you console.log out what `message.author.joinedTimestamp` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message.author` is a `User` and it doesn't have a `joinedTimestamp` property, only `GuildMember`s have. [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) represents the author of the message as a guild member, so you can use that as it will have a [`joinedTimestamp`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=joinedTimestamp) property.

The reason you see `NaN` instead of the correct value is because `parseInt` will return `NaN` if you try to parse `undefined`:

```js
console.log('undefined:', parseInt(undefined / 1000, 10));
console.log('3459192421512:', parseInt(3459192421512 / 1000, 10));
```

The following code should work as expected

```js
.addFields(
  { name: 'ID', value: message.author.id },
  {
    name: 'Joined Server',
    value: `<t:${parseInt(message.member.joinedTimestamp / 1000, 10)}:R>`,
    inline: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Account Created',
    value: `<t:${parseInt(message.author.createdTimestamp / 1000, 10)}:R>`,
    inline: true,
  },
);
```

As for `target`, it's the same issue; `message.mentions.users.first()` is a `User`. You could create a new variable, e.g. `targetMember` and assign `message.mentions.members.first()`, so it will be a `GuildMember`:

```js
const target = message.mentions.users.first();
const targetMember = message.mentions.members.first();
```

And then, just replace `target`:

```js
.addFields(
  { name: 'ID', value: target.id },
  {
    name: 'Joined Server',
    value: `<t:${parseInt(targetMember.joinedTimestamp / 1000, 10)}:R>`,
    inline: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Account Created',
    value: `<t:${parseInt(target.createdTimestamp / 1000, 10)}:R>`,
    inline: true,
  },
);
```

PS: It's a good idea to [use the radix in `parseInt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611824/why-do-we-need-to-use-radix-parameter-when-calling-parseint). That's why I added `10` as the second parameter in `parseInt`.

Comment: what about target.member.joinedTimeStamp?

Answer (score 0):

Could you verify the type of `target.joinedTimestamp`?

It could be that the double conversion you are doing here:

```js
parseInt(target.joinedTimestamp / 1000)
```

destroyed your number.

(You are converting whatever `target.createdTimestamp` is to number, dividing it by 100 (making it a floating point number) and then discarding the floating point by converting back to int.)

Comment: ok so how can I make a joined The server: Time stamp?

Comment: You can find out the type of target.joinedTimestamp by using JavaScripts typeof(target.joinedTimestamp) or by using your debugger.

You could also try to convert it to a date by wrapping target.joinedTimestamp into new Date like this: `new Date(target.joinedTimestamp)`.

The line would then look like `{name: "Joined Server", value: \`<t:${parseInt(new Date(target.joinedTimestamp) / 1000)}:R>\`, inline: true},`