# If statement inside function on Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

I cant find the issue here also as I want to display text and other text if the check box is checked

```
<script>

function showconf() {

var checkbox = document.getElementById('check');

if (checkBox.checked == true){
 document.getElementById('show').value = "test" ;
 
 }
 
 else {
 document.getElementById('show').value = "hello"  ;
 
 }
 
 }
 
 </script>

 
 <body>
 
 <input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="showconf()" >
 <textarea id="show" name="message" rows="30" cols="100"></textarea>
 
 </body>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You have a syntax error `getElementById.(Text1)` remove the `.` Also, you have to convert `.value` to a number

Comment: @KonradLinkowski `parseInt(string)`.

Comment: @Shmack `parseInt` without the second argument is unsafe. I would rather use `Number()` or just `+` operator.

Comment: You have a few typos: You aren't declaring the variables **Text1** and **Text3**  anywhere. So you either need to declare them OR just wrap them in quotes to access those fields. And remove the period after **getElementById**

Comment: @KonradLinkowski is unsafe the proper word for this use case? From what I find, its more inefficient than unsafe.

Comment: I meant [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611824/why-do-we-need-to-use-radix-parameter-when-calling-parseint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing many syntax errors. first there are so many dots (.) in your `document.getElementById()` remove that and the value of `document.getElementById(Text1)` should be `document.getElementById('Text1')` between quotes `'` or double quotes `"`. I have fixed everything now it will work good. Below is your fixed code.

```
<script>
  function hello (){
    var x = document.getElementById('Text1').value;
    if (x>10){
      document.getElementById('Text3').value = "1";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('Text3').value = "2";
    }
  }
</script> 

<body>
  <input type="text" id="Text1" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" onclick="hello()"  value="Click..."/>
  <input type="text" id="Text3"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are referencing DOM elements  :

- remember to use " in .getElementById : getElementById("Text1")
  Try this:

```html
<script>
  function hello (){
    var x = document.getElementById("Text1").value;
    if (x>10){
        document.getElementById("Text3").value= "1";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("Text3").value= "2";
    }
}
</script>





<body>

  <input type="text" id="Text1" />

  <br/>
  <input type="button" onclick="hello()"  value="Click..."/>

  <input type="text" id="Text3"/>

</body>
```